# Failed to load font_properties from font_properties

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm new to tesseract. I tried to start training the tesseract but while creating shapetable file in command prompt, it was throwing some error like '**Failed to load font_properties from font_properties**'. Did anyone faced the same issue before? Can you let me know how to fix this pls.

Code : `shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset -O block.unicharset block.font.exp0.tr`

Error : `Failed to load font_properties from font_properties`

[image: 1]

Comment: `font_properties` file exists? It may need an ending blank line.

Comment: @nguyenq yes, the font properties file is there with a blank line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Does font_properties exists? What is in it?

BTW: tesseract training is waste of time for new tesseract users.

Comment: How does the new tesseract works. I'm not sure about that. Can you let me know some hints pls

Comment: yes I had the font_properties text file in the folder and it has 'font 0 0 0 0 0 blank line at the end' –